# Terminate Process from Different Script?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am writing a program that uses tkinter to control python scripts that run a High voltage system. The system itself works fine, but I need a way to "crash" the system. The system slowly ticks up the voltage until it reaches its goal voltage. However if something goes wrong I want a separate program running that is basically a big button that shuts down the main voltage ticker and takes over basically setting the voltage to zero. Since the ticker is looping, the tkinter window freezes up until the process is finished and I can't control it. I was wondering if there is a way to control one python process from another program to interrupt the process and accept new instructions.

Comment: I know this is not what you asked, but if you were using threads, you could try the `_thread.interrupt_main` method. As you are not, I have to ask what system you are using as, on a Unix system, you *could* utilise signals. Other solutions would be to use subprocess pipes and sockets.

Comment: I am using a raspberry pi actually. Im a novice so I don't really know too much outside of intermediate python and c++